# Вывод двух связанных таблиц

Tags: php, html, javascript, sql

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что необходимо вывести две таблицы (или любой другой список) так, чтобы в левой таблице мы могли выбирать определенный пункт, а в правой таблице, при выборе разных пунктов в левой таблице, отображались пункты, которые привязаны к пункту в левой. 
Допустим у нас есть СписокКомплекующих1, СписокКомплектующих 2 и т.д. Это пункты в первой таблице. И все эти комплектующие записаны в базе данных в таблице Списки комплектующих. И в каждом этом списке комплектующих есть, соотвественно, сами комплектующие - видеокарта1, видеокарта2 и т.д. И для каждого списка комплектующие разные. Для этих комплектующих есть вторая таблица в базе, где СписокКомплектующих1 или любой другой указан в качестве внешнего ключа. Нужно, чтобы в левой таблице на странице отображались названия списков комплектующих и при выборе определенного списка в левой таблице отображались нужные комплектующие, привязанные к этим спискам. И пользователь может выбирать только из одного списка определенные комплектующие и они, соответственно, записываются в базу. 
Вопрос в том, как реализовать эти таблицы? Как реализовать одну таблицу я знаю без проблем. А вот как две синхронизированные между собой не очень.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsReferences)) {
$html .= '<p><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="' . $row['reference'] . '" />' . $row['reference'].'</p>';
}
```

Это список на чекбоксах. Нужен еще второй список из радиобаттонов, чтобы чекбоксы менялись в зависимости от выбранного радиобаттона. Можно все это реализовать и таблицей.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: MYSQL DEPRECATED

[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto А когда появится надпись "php deprecated"?

Comment: коротко говоря - можно :) но полный код тут не приложишь. Я не уверен, что на данном ресурсе есть понятие лички, зайдите ко мне в профиль там адрес сайта, на котором есть контактная форма, напишите помогу разобраться